# Equivalent of main() in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I am new to android.

I have two activities, say ActivityA & ActivityB. I have put open an HTTP connection  code in onCreate() of ActivityA and update ActivityB with the information i retrieve with HTTP, i send this data to ActivityB via Intents.

Now when i switch to ActivityB the onCreate() of AcitivityB starts and i no longer have access to the HTTP connection i opened in ActivityA. One option for me is to open new connection in ActivityB but that obviously is not a proper way.

How could i resolve this? How could i have like a main() function where i keep the http connection open, send the data recieved to different activities & show them but execution returns back to my http connection code after the activities are displayed?

Thanks.

Comment: You can always refer the objects in an Activity, if they are declared `protected static`. Simply refer to them like `MyActivity.myObject`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the HTTP code in your `Application` class, that way it will be visible to all your Activities and be persisted thru the lifecycle of the app.

Apart from that, there is no `main()` equivallent, only use-cases in which different methods can be used instead of `main()` - such as `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, and so on...

Comment: Thanks everyone, thank you shark, Application class worked great for me. :)

Comment: You're very much welcome, I had a need for a similar long-lived object that should be initialized at the beginning of `main()` and closed near the end of `main()` and I found the `Application` class to be the right place for that object because you can easily introduce callbacks which your `Activities` and `Fragments` can implement (and receive) easily.

The object I needed was a `BroadcastReceiver` to broadcast received GCM events to the "active activity" but it looks similar because you're after a similar purpose and use-case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Create a singleton class to your connection. That way you will always have (only) one connection open, that can be accessed by other classes/activities.

Comment: And remember to close it in `onPause()` and reopen it in `onResume()` to prevent memory leaks...